# PC ping script in Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, ping

The script constantly pings a list of PC hostnames from the import CSV column 1.

> Column 1 (Hostname) Column 2 (User) ←Manually updated field.

When the script recognises 3 failed ping attempts, it emails our email address with Time/Hostname/Owner (Taken from the .csv file) From/IP address/Failed Pings.

This works perfectly. However, when the the PC comes back online it sends another email with the above but will not show the correct owner. Can someone please help with associating `$Back` "owner" with the appropriate User? Like it works with the initial email response. At the moment it will either show nothing or the last name in the User column on the email, regardless the first notification email is correct.

```
$computers = Import-Csv C:\temp\Reporting\MainHosts.csv
$Sources = @($Env:COMPUTERNAME)
$To = "Username@Email.com"#,"Username@Email.com"
$From = "Username@Email.com"
$SMTPServer = "SERVER"
[datetime]$TimeStop = "16:17"
$StartTime = Get-Date -format 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'

Clear-Host

$Header = @"
    <style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 11pt;}
    TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;}
    TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;text-align: center;}
    TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;text-align: center;}
    </style>
"@

######################Load data array (Table) ######################
$Status = @{}
foreach ($Source in $Sources) {
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $computername = $($computer.Hostname)
        $owner = $($computer.User)
        $Status.Add("$Source`:$computername", [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time = ""
            Hostname = $computername
            Owner = $owner
            From = $Source
            'IP Address' = $null
            'Failed Pings' = 0
        })
    }
}

###################### Script Begin Message ######################
do {
    $Results = foreach ($Source in $Sources) {
        foreach ($computer in $computers) {
            $computername = $($computer.Hostname) #Defining the Hostname column within .csv sheet
            $owner = $($computer.User)
            try {
                Write-Host "." -NoNewline
                Get-WmiObject "Win32_PingStatus" -ComputerName $Source -Filter "Address = '$computername'" -ErrorAction Stop | Select PSComputerName,Address,IPV4Address,StatusCode
            } catch {
                Write-Warning "Error with $computername`: $($Error[0])"
            }
        }
    }

    $Back = @()
    foreach ($Result in $Results) {
        $Key = "$($Result.PSComputerName):$($Result.Address)"
        $Status[$Key].'IP Address' = $Result.IPV4Address
        $Status[$Key].Time = Get-Date
        if ($Result.StatusCode -eq 0) {
            if ($Status[$Key].'Failed Pings' -ge 3) {
                $Back += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Time = Get-Date
                    Hostname = $Result.Address
                    Owner = $owner
                    From = $Result.PSComputerName
                    IPAddress = $Result.IPV4Address
                    Status = "Connectivity Returned"
                }
            }
            $Status[$Key].'Failed Pings' = 0
        } else {
            $Status[$Key].'Failed Pings' ++
        }
    }
    # Email Alert
    if ($Back) {
        $HTML = $Back | Sort Destination,From | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "<p>Ping Detection Script has detected the following workstations are now online and <b>restored connectivity!</b><br></p>" | Out-String
        Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $From -Subject "**No Action Required** - Ping Detection Script Reporting Connections Restored" -Body $HTML -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
    }

    $Data = $Status.Values | Where { $_.'Failed Pings' -eq 3 -or ( ($_.'Failed Pings' -ne 0 -and -not ($_.'Failed Pings' % $Alert))) }
    if ($Data) {
        $HTML = $Data | Sort Destination,From | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "<p>Ping Detection Script has detected <b>Offline</b> workstations! See below list<br></p>" | Out-String
        Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $From -Subject "**Urgent Action Required** - Ping Detection Script Reporting Offline Workstations" -Body $HTML -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
        Write-Host "Alert Email Sent!`n"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }

    Clear-Host
    $Status.Values | Sort Destination,From | Format-Table -AutoSize
    Write-Host "Ping Script Monitoring ..." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
} until ($Time.Hour -eq $TimeStop.Hour -and $Time.Minute -eq $TimeStop.Minute)
Write-Host "`nScript shutting down, time limit reached:  $($TimeStop.Hour):$($TimeStop.Minute)"
Write-Output $Status.Values | Sort Destination,From | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add the `$Owner` to the WMI object at the first embedded loop after `Script Begin Message` (and use `...Owner = $Result...`):

```
...
Try {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    $Result = Get-WmiObject "Win32_PingStatus" -ComputerName $Source -Filter "Address = '$computername'" -ErrorAction Stop | Select PSComputerName,Address,IPV4Address,StatusCode
    $Result = $Result | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Owner $Owner
   $Result
} Catch {
...
```

Or forget about the owner in the first embedded loop and retrieve the owner on the fly (`Owner = $Computers | Where {$_.Name = $Result.PSComputerName}`) in the `foreach ($Result in $Results) {...` loop:

```
$Back += [PSCustomObject]@{
    Time = Get-Date
    Hostname = $Result.Address
    Owner = $Computers | Where {$_.Name = $Result.PSComputerName}
    From = $Result.PSComputerName
    IPAddress = $Result.IPV4Address
    Status = "Connectivity Returned"
}
```